# kableExtra stops evaluating latex code in table

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I have an R Markdown table with this `\rule{1cm}{0.4pt}` LaTeX command in each cell of one column. The table formats just fine with `kable` if I do not include the `kableExtra` package. If I do include `kabelExtra,` the LaTeX command is no longer interpreted. The results are shown below, without and with kableExtra. No other change was made. The top example is my desired result.

I inspected the .tex output. `kableExtra` seems to format the LaTeX command as literal text: `\textbackslash{}rule\{1cm\}\{0.4pt\}` instead of the command shown above.

I want to use kableExtra for other features like setting column widths but I need it to interpret the LaTeX commands. I did not find anything in the manual or vignettes that seemed to address included LateX commands. Am I missing something?

#### Edit

I tried adding `format = "latex"` to the `kable` call when using `kableExtra` but undesired result remained.

#### MWE

````
---
title: "Without kableExtra"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    keep_tex: TRUE
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
library(tibble)
library(knitr)
#library(kableExtra)

a = seq(1:3)
b = seq(4:6)
tab <- as.tibble(cbind(a,b))
tab <- add_column(tab, c = "\\rule{1cm}{0.4pt}")
```

```{r}
kable(tab,
      booktabs = TRUE, 
      longtable = TRUE)
```
````

#### Results

[image: without and with kableExtra]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `kableExtra` you should add the argument `escape = FALSE` to your `kable()` call. The `escape` argument let you use LaTeX commands in table.

The following works:

````
---
title: "Without kableExtra"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    keep_tex: TRUE
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
library(tibble)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

a = seq(1:3)
b = seq(4:6)
tab <- as.tibble(cbind(a,b))
tab <- add_column(tab, c = "\\rule{1cm}{0.4pt}")
```

```{r}
kable(tab,
      booktabs = TRUE, 
      longtable = TRUE,
      escape = FALSE)
```
````

Comment: I figured I had to be missing something. I was looking for an option that affected the table as a whole, not specific cells. If only I could get through life without making assumptions!